# Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord?

Tags: android, timeout, android-activity

```
W/ActivityManager(   81): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
W/ActivityManager(   81): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord
```

Does anyone know what reason would cause this happens?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this recently. Is it possible that you're experiencing this after last update on Nexus One?

Comment: I guess it is caused by some processing is blocking the main thread, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means that the Activity cannot be displayed because it is still trying to complete execution; meanwhile the ActivityManager has timed out.

I had the same problem, and managed to resolve it by tidying up dependencies between Activity objects.

I would recommend starting up the debugger. Look at any 'services' that your Activity depends on (e.g. http client, parsers etc.) and check that it is not blocking. If you have 'services' that are shared between Activity objects, it might also be worth checking that they still exist in memory as GC may have destroyed any statically referenced service objects or objects cached as WeakReference objects.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.
Inside my View.dispatchDraw(), I was calling a method that triggered another dispatchDraw().
(Adding a logline inside my dispatchDraw() showed that the function was called continuously.
This did not show up when doing method profiling in Eclipse)

Hope this is helpful to someone.