# image switching on button click

Tags: android, image, switching, buttonclick

I have tries to switch the images on button click..but i failed and got the errors
Here is my code....please somebody help me!!
please add XML code if required also please post the same also

```
package com.conn;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory;

public class image_slider extends Activity
{

        Integer[] imageIDs = { R.drawable.haha,  R.drawable.dte,R.drawable.new_login };
        private ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher;
        private Button nextButton;
        private Button previousButton; 

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.imgslide);
            imageSwitcher.setImageResource(imageIDs[0]);
            nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
            nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    final Animation out= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);       
                    final Animation in= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);     
                    imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher1);      
                    imageSwitcher.setFactory(this);   
                    imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);      
                    imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out);             
                    imageSwitcher.setImageResource(imageIDs[1]);
//                  imageSwitcher.setImageResource(imageIDs[1]);

                }

            }); 

            previousButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
            previousButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    final Animation out= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_left);
                    final Animation in= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_right);
                    imageSwitcher.setFactory(this);
                    imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);
                    imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out);
                    imageSwitcher.setImageResource(imageIDs[0]);

                }

            });
        }
public View makeView()
    {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        return imageView;
    }       

}
```

Comment: what errors did you get?

Comment: loadAnimation of previous button i got The method loadAnimation(Context, int) in the type AnimationUtils is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, int)

Comment: Also in "slide_out_left" and "slide_in_right" red underline is coming saying "slide_in_right/slide_out_left cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: thank u again...and wat about the setFactory!!!!!!!!!!!1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you refer to `this` in your `OnClickListener` your are referring to that particular listener and not to your current Activity. You should change it to

```
 final Animation out= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(image_slider.this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right); 
 final Animation in= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(image_slider.this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
 ...
 imageSwitcher.setFactory(image_slider.this);
```

And use `android.R.anim.slide_in_left` and `android.R.anim.slide_out_right` not slide_out_left and "slide_in_right" because these don't exist.

BTW, good Java practice is to start your class name with a capital letter, e.g. `ImageSlider`

Comment: 06-20 19:03:41.111: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{45148388 com.conn/.image_slider}
                                                                    now i am getting this error while running...huh...plz help..

Comment: Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283449/activity-idle-timeout-for-historyrecord) for a solution, or create a new question for it.