# Toast message from Java class

Tags: java, android, toast

I'm developing a `card game`. In the `main class` of the game called "Mesa" where it fires the main loop of the game I want to Toast some message to see if it works and the next step I want to do if this runs is build the User Interface for this game.
All this message I want to show, are Logged sing Log.d(... , ... ) and it works fine. The problem I have is that it seems that screen turns black when trying to `Toast` these messages.
Here's my `class` for `Toast` messages:

```
public class ToastMsg
{

    Context ctx;

    public ToastMsg (Context context)
    {
        this.ctx = context;
    }

    public void makeText(final String text)
    {
           Handler handler = new Handler();        
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ctx, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Here is my `onCreate` Method from `Principal.class` where I create a new "Mesa"

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
    mesa = new Mesa(Principal.this, 3, 1, 3);
    mesa.añadirJugador(new JugadorBot("Jose"));
    mesa.añadirJugador(new JugadorBot("Hasan"));
    mesa.añadirJugador(new JugadorBot("Abdul"));

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                mesa.empezarPartida();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("ERROR", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

}
```

In the logCat i get an  Error:

```
06-21 11:55:05.558: W/ActivityManager(1273): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
06-21 11:55:05.848: E/WindowManager(1273): Starting window AppWindowToken{b3307548 token=Token{b333f7a8 ActivityRecord{b3398748 u0 com.games.sardineta/.Principal t3}}} timed out
```

EDIT:

Here's for example when Toastmessage method is used: (This is a method form a class representing a Deck)

```
public void repartir (int cartas, Jugada jugada)
{
    /* MÃ©tedo que recibe el nÃºmero de cartas a repartir
     *  y los jugadores. Reparte cartas a los jugadores
     *  uno a uno.
     */
    ArrayList<Jugador> jugadores = jugada.mesa.jugadores;
    for (int i=1; i<=cartas; i++)
    {
        for (Jugador jugador : jugadores)
        {
            try
            {
                Carta carta = baraja.get(0);
                jugador.getMano().add(carta);
                baraja.remove(0);
                Log.d("DEBUG", jugador.getNombre() + " recibe " + carta.toString());
                jugada.mesa.toast.makeText(jugador.getNombre() + " recibe " + carta.toString());
                sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (NullPointerException npe)
            {
                throw new Error ("Baraja vacía.");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
public class Mesa {

Principal ctx;
public ToastMsg toast;
......
public Mesa (Context ctx, int numeroJugadores, int numBarajas, int numCartasRepartir)
{
    if (numeroJugadores < 2 || numeroJugadores > NUMERO_MAX_DE_JUGADORES)
        throw new Error ("Número de jugadores no válido.");
    this.ctx = (Principal) ctx;
    toast = new ToastMsg(ctx.getApplicationContext());
     ....
 }}
```

Any ideas?
Some help would be appreciate.

Comment: where calling `ToastMsg` method?

Comment: Why are you using a handler and `runOnUiThread()` for something so simple? Your `onCreate()` method is **already** running on the UI thread.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Note that `ToastMsg()` is a constructor, not a method. Still, point taken. I don't see anywhere a `ToastMsg` object is created.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: OP is creating object of `Mesa` class instead of `ToastMsg` that's why i'm asking

Comment: you are getting this error as you are doing lot of work on the main ui thread.

Comment: Jose, please edit your original post for the additional information requested. Mult-line code snippets cannot be formatted in a comment.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo: show  `Jugada` class code also

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489376/warn-activitymanager78-launch-timeout-has-expired-giving-up-wake-lock-wh) might useful for you.

Comment: Suggestions: 1. Get rid of the Handler. It is absolutely unnecessary. 2. Do **not** catch `NullPointerException`s. If these ever occur, you need to know immediately as they signal an error in your programming logic. NPE should **never** occur in the final version of your app for users. And they certainly shouldn't be caught allowing the app to continue in an unstable state.

Comment: Also, unrelated to this question, I suggest you learn about encapsulation and data-hiding. Also, learn how to use private variables.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo: Just change `ToastMsg(ctx.getApplicationContext())` to `ToastMsg(ctx)` no need to use Application context to show Toast message

Comment: Thank  you guys for your answers but I still getting the same error. I can't figure out how some simple thing could be so problematic.